# Test existence of a macro in Twig 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to be able to test the existence of a macro in Twig and to call it dynamically.

Here is what I tried:

```
{% macro test(value) %}
    Value: {{ value }}
{% endmacro %}

{% import "_macros.html.twig" as macro %}

{{ attribute(macro, 'test', ['foo']) }}
```

But I get this error: `Accessing Twig_Template attributes is forbidden.`

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Twig 1.20.0, template attributes are not available anymore for security reasons, so there are no native way to do it properly.

You can eventually use the [`source`](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/source.html) function to get macro's source file and parse it to check if a macro exists, but that's a kind of ugly hack easy to bypass.

Example:

<kbd>main.twig</kbd>

```
{% import 'macros.twig' as macros %}

{% set sourceMacros = source(macros) %}

foo {% if 'foo()' in sourceMacros %} exists {% else %} does not exist {% endif %}

bar {% if 'bar()' in sourceMacros %} exists {% else %} does not exist {% endif %}
```

<kbd>macros.twig</kbd>

```
{% macro foo() %}
Hello, world!
{% endmacro %}
```

See [this example live](https://twigfiddle.com/22ense)

Another approach would be to create a [custom test](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/advanced.html#tests) to do the job.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't know about `source`. If your macro has params, e.g. `{% macro foo(bar) %}`, you would have to update `'foo()'` to match the source verbatim e.g. `'foo(bar)'` or  `'{% macro foo('`.